# Does Hindu scripture have statements approximating "you can't step into the same river twice"?

Tags: scripture, life, human

https://theinvisiblementor.com/you-cannot-step-into-the-same-river-twice/

> you cannot step into the same river twice because you are changing and the river is changing

I think this describes the transitoriness of human existence.  Do Hindu scriptures have equivalent statements?

Comment: you got it right @rickross

Comment: The tag u created probably will be put to death so I added a valid tag for the question

Comment: Watch this if you understand Hindi from [50.20](https://youtu.be/mhZZmeajVy8)

Comment: very nice @Mr. Sigma.

Comment: Words fail me to charcterize tagging this post "rivers".

Comment: It's probably worth noting that Heraclitus' statement is not really about "the transitory nature of human existence" but is about the opposition between the "same river" and "different waters" — the fact that the water is changing is what makes the river a river. That makes it very different from quotes like "youth is like a flower".

Comment: I suppose it DOES apply to an immortal you and an immortal river  @mattdm - but that everything is fleeting is also consistent with the statement (whether inevitable death awaits at the end of all the flux is not strictly material).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following verse is saying the same:

> Sampadah swapna samkAshA yauvanam kusumopamam |
>   TaricchanchalamAyushcha kasya syAjjAnato dhritih ||
>
> Wealth (prosperity) is like a dream. Youth is like a flower/blossom (i.e it withers in no
>   time). Life-span is momentary like lightning. Who can have patience after
>   knowing all these?
>
> *KulArnava Tantram 1.30*

This verse and many other verses of the same chapter are talking about how short lived we are and how much less time we have to accomplish what we have to.

> Pratikshanamaym kAyo jirnamAno na lakshyate |
>  Amkumbha
>   ivAmbhahstho vishirno naiva bhAvyate ||
>
> The ignorant man fails to see that with every moment his body decays.
>   He does not think over the fact that, like an earthen pot kept immersed
>   in water, his body too is decaying with every passing moment.
>
> *KulArnava Tantram 1.37*

There are many verses in this chapter like these two which have a similar purport.

Comment: I must continue reading kularnava Tantra. There is a lot to know.

Comment: Yes and all of this is from the 1st chapter itself @TheLittleNaruto